# ffpmeg drops last frame when compressing from MP4 to MP4 (libx264)

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, encode, mp4, libx264

So, I'm using this code to compress my *mp4 file. I need to get lower quality and decrease bitrate:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

The problem is: the last frame of footage is dropped after ffmpeg compression.
Screenshot is here: [screenshot_ffmpeg_drop frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj2wn.png)

I tried to use full preferences I need, but the problem is the same.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:720 -preset fast -crf 29 -r 25 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

logfile during ffmpeg encoding:

> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\input.mp4':
>     Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp42
>       minor_version   : 0
>       compatible_brands: mp42mp41
>       creation_time   : 2018-10-28T11:06:03.000000Z
>     Duration: 00:00:12.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5374 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5368 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2018-10-28T11:06:03.000000Z
>         handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
>         encoder         : AVC Coding
>
> Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264
>   (libx264)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [libx264 @
>   000002fae8b50780] using SAR=1/1 [libx264 @ 000002fae8b50780] using cpu
>   capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 [libx264 @
>   000002fae8b50780] profile High, level 3.1 [libx264 @ 000002fae8b50780]
>   264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft
>   2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=2
>   deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
>   mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0
>   deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12
>   lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
>   bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
>   b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250
>   keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=crf
>   mbtree=1 crf=29.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
>   aq=1:1.00 Output #0, mp4, to '\output.mp4':   Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp42
>       minor_version   : 0
>       compatible_brands: mp42mp41
>       encoder         : Lavf58.17.100
>       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25
>   tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2018-10-28T11:06:03.000000Z
>         handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
>         encoder         : Lavc58.19.104 libx264
>       Side data:
>         cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
>
> frame=  318 fps=127 q=-1.0 Lsize=     855kB time=00:00:12.60 bitrate=
>   556.0kbits/s speed=5.05x video:851kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.534683% [libx264 @
>   0000015d5cef0500] frame I:2     Avg QP:26.18  size: 67800 [libx264 @
>   0000015d5cef0500] frame P:80    Avg QP:27.93  size:  5439 [libx264 @
>   0000015d5cef0500] frame B:236   Avg QP:32.44  size:  1269 [libx264 @
>   0000015d5cef0500] consecutive B-frames:  0.9%  0.0%  0.9% 98.1%
>   [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500] mb I  I16..4: 10.6% 62.5% 26.8% [libx264
>   @ 0000015d5cef0500] mb P  I16..4:  0.5%  1.0%  0.2%  P16..4: 36.1% 
>   5.1%  3.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:53.6% [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500] mb B  I16..4:  0.6%  0.5%  0.0%  B16..8: 22.2%  0.6%  0.0%  direct: 2.0% 
>   skip:74.2%  L0:44.9% L1:54.5% BI: 0.6% [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500]
>   8x8 transform intra:55.0% inter:86.2% [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500]
>   coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 48.1% 54.9% 27.0% inter: 3.2% 5.2% 0.2%
>   [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500] i16 v,h,dc,p: 19% 56% 10% 15% [libx264 @
>   0000015d5cef0500] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 25% 18%  5%  6% 
>   5%  8%  5%  8% [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500] i4
>   v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 24%  9%  5%  8%  7%  9%  5%  7%
>   [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500] i8c dc,h,v,p: 60% 20% 15%  4% [libx264 @
>   0000015d5cef0500] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0% [libx264 @
>   0000015d5cef0500] ref P L0: 67.7% 32.3% [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500]
>   ref B L0: 80.4% 19.6% [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500] ref B L1: 92.1% 
>   7.9% [libx264 @ 0000015d5cef0500] kb/s:547.35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ignore_editlist 1 -i input.mp4 ... output.mp4
```

Comment: Gyan, thanks for your help. I tried your code and still last frame is dropped. BTW I've no audio stream in input video (if it matters)

Comment: This is the reference video file: https://127923.selcdn.ru/links/input.mp4 Timecode on the screen is 00:00:12:18 at the last frame, but after compression by ffmpeg it is 00:00:12:17

Comment: This is why you should post the full log. The relevant msgs were printed before the portion you pasted. Cmd edited. You only need to add one option.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine! I would be highly appreciated if you could explain the solution.